# Spring - accessing Model values in JSP which names contain "-" (minus sign)

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a mapper, which maps some `String`s to `Object`s and then adds them to `ModelAndView`. Now in JSP I want to use this values, for example:

- **JAVA**

`ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("sometemplate");
model.addObject("name-with-hyphens", "hello world");`

- **JSP**

```html
<input type="text" name="foo" class="input" placeholder="bar" value="${name-with-hyphens}" />
```

However, input field has value 0 but - and I checked - without hyphens/minus sign this would be empty and placeholder value would be visible. My guess is that this is interpreted as some mathematic operations; how can I make this work as intended?
For various reasons, things would be easier for me and my app if I could use hyphens, instead of other signs (less parsing and string operations in my code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not going to work because dash is not valid Java identifier. Avoid using dash if you want to work it. See here for [[common mistakes]](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30946&seqNum=10) in jstl expression language.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no portable way in EL to hide operators and use them in variable names, and could not find anything about that in JSP2.3 specification ([JSR245](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245)).